# Sql Query to retrieve a particular data from particular column and row in android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I want to fetch phone number linked to particular email in the database. I am not able to find the query for it or how

```
public String getContactNumber(String email){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER + " FROM " + TABLE_USER + " WHERE " + email +  " = " + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
            //What to put here to extract the data.

            String contact = cursor.getString(get); 
            cursor.close();
            return contact;
        }
```

to extract the data. Completely a beginner

Comment: just pass some SQLite tutorial for Android. Don't be lazy, it should not take much time, but will elliminate most part of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
public List<String> getMyItemsD(String emailData) {
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER FROM " + USER_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE email= " + emailData;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
            String name = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Item_Name")));

            stringList.add(name);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return stringList;
}
```

Comment: Will this give a particular value as I am confused as it will provide value stored in List and then how to pass those value in another function.

Comment: 1. Checking a Cursor returned from an SQLiteDatabase method for **null** is **useless**, it will not be null. 2. traversing a Cursor does not need to be so complicated you can simply utilise the return code from moveToNext using `while (c.moveToNext()) { stringList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Item_Name")))}`. 3. You should ALWAYS close a Cursor when done with it, so before `return stringList ` you should have `c.close();`

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getContactNumber(String email){
    String contact = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER + " FROM " + TABLE_USER + " WHERE " + email +  " = " + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
        cursor.moveToNext();
        contact = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER)); 
    }
    //What to put here to extract the data.                             
    cursor.close();
    return contact;
}
```

From this method you get phone number value of that email which you pass any other method easily.

Comment: `if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { contact = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER));}` would be simpler as most of the **moveTo????** methods return true if the move were made else false if the move could not be made.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following :-

```
public String getContactNumber(String email){
    String contact = "NO CONTACT FOUND"; //<<<<<<<<<< Default in case no row is found.
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<<<<<<< Generally getReadable gets a writable database 
    String[] columns_to_get = new String[]{COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER};
    String whereclause = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{email};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,columns_to_get,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    //What to put here to extract the data.
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contact = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_MOBILE_NUMBER));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return contact;
}
```

- The above does assumes that there will only be 1 row per email (which is most likely).

### Explanations

A default value is set so that you can easily tell if an invalid/non-existent email is passed (you'd check the return value if need be (might be easier to simply have "" and check the length as a check)).

**getReadableDatabase** has been replaced with **getWritableDatabase** as unless there are issues with the database a writable database will be returned, as per :-

> Create and/or open a database. This will be the same object returned
>   by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk,
>   requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a
>   read-only database object will be returned. If the problem is fixed, a
>   future call to getWritableDatabase() may succeed, in which case the
>   read-only database object will be closed and the read/write object
>   will be returned in the future.
>   [getReadableDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#getReadableDatabase())

- Note no real problem either way;

The recommended **query** method has been used instead of the **rawQuery** method. This has distinct advantages, it builds the underlying SQL and also offers protection against SQL injection (just in case the email passed is input by a user).

- this version of the method takes 7 parameters :-

  - The table name as a string
  - The columns to be extracted as an array of Strings (aka String array). **null** can be all columns.
  - The where clause less the WHERE keyword with ?'s to represent arguments (see next). **null** if no WHERE clause.
  - The arguments to be applied (replace ?'s 1 for 1) as a String array. **null** if none or no WHERE clause.
  - The GROUP BY clause, less the GROUP BY keywords. **null** if no GROUP BY clause.
  - The HAVING clause, less the HAVING keyword. **null** if no HAVING clause.
  - The ORDER BY clause, less the ORDER BY keywords. **null** if no ORDER BY clause.

[SQLiteDatabase - query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
- Note there are 4 query methods (see link for the subtle difference, I believe this is the most commonly used)

The data extraction is the new code. When a Cursor is returned it is at a position BEFORE THE FIRST ROW, so you need to move to a valid row. So the **moveToFirst* method is suitable *(note that if a move cannot be made by a move method that it will return false, hence how you can say `if (cursor.moveToFirst())`)*. The data is then extracted from the appropriate column use the **getString** method, which takes an int as an argumnet for the column offset (0 in this case). However, using hard coded values can lead to issues so the **getColumnIndex** method is used to get the offset according to the column name (-1 is returned if the named column is not in the Cursor).